# Oracle 11g resource manager clarification

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm hoping that someone can just confirm my understanding of how the resource manager works...

If I've got a 4 node RAC with 2 consumer groups and 2 services, the services send each consumer group to one node only i.e. consumer group 1 ALWAYS gets sent to node 1 and 2 and consumer group 2 ALWAYS gets sent to node 3 and 4.

If I've got a tiered resource plan such as:

```
Group Name | L0  | L1  | max

Group 1    | 75% | 0   | 80%

Group 2    | 0   | 75% | 80%
```

Am I right in saying that as group 1 is on nodes 1 and 2 and group 2 is on nodes 3 and 4, they will each have 75% of resources available on their respective nodes? and both be limited to 80% on the node they are running on?

i.e. Resources are constricted and calculated on a per node basis and not a per cluster.

So just because a connection on node 1 group 1 is using 80% of resources, another connection on node 2 group 1 will have up to 80% available to it and not 0%.

And similarly if group 1 is using its allocated maximum, group 2 will also get its full share on nodes 3 and 4 as group 1 which is of higher priority isn't running on those nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a response from Oracle Support:

> Resource management's limits are applied per node except PARALLEL_TARGET_PERCENTAGE, so for your example, you are right.
>
> Connections in consumer group 2 only ever hit node 2 (due to the
> services), group 2 will get a minimum of 75% of resources on the 2nd
> node and potentially 100% if no max limit has been set or 80% if the max limit has been set.